# In-memory event queue for PHP

Tags: php, facebook, events, event-handling, queue

I have hundreds of event producers and each event producer has hundreds of event subscribers. I need to notify (asynchronously) my event consumers (final users) of the new events. It is somewhat similar to Facebook's event feed. I can't use database JOINs, as the performance of queries degrade exponentially as the number of conditions in WHERE clause reach hundreds. I could store individual user event feeds in separate table, however that will cause hundreds of INSERTS for every event and the table will get too big too fast. I am looking towards publisher-subscriber method, which means that every user gets own event queue, which is constantly updated with new events, until he/she "consumes" them by visiting event feed.

I am looking for an event queue, which can run on Ubuntu, use FIFO (first in, first out) method and have a limited queue size. For example I set queue size to 10 events. Every user (hundreds of thousands) has a queue. When producer generates an event, all subscribers get event pushed at the top of the queue. If any of them opens the event feed, the queue (containing event ids) is sent to front-end server, which pulls event data from DB and sends to client, while queue stays intact. Then when more events are produced, they "push" the older events out of the queue.

Main requirement is that event queue either has PHP extension to work with or such extension can be easily written. Speed and data backup is important, but not a priority.

Comment: I think this might close as "recommendation for library", sadly, as interesting as it is. What is the reason that you cannot use JOINs though? I didn't follow that bit.

Comment: @halfer I've edited the questions to make it more clear. I found one forum discussion about the topic, but it has no suggestions for implementation. Writing this off scratch is not currently feasible for the project.